# message.content.startsWith is not a function error

Tags: function, discord, discord.js, prefix

**here is my code**

```js
const prefix = '!';

module.exports = {
    name: 'messageCreate',
    once: false,
    execute(client, message) {
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        if (!message.content.startWith(prefix)) return;

        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
        const cmdName = args.shift().toLowerCase()
        if (cmdName.length == 0) return;

        let cmd = client.commands.get(cmdName)
        if (cmd) cmd.run(client, message, args)
    }
}
```

It gives me this error: `TypeError: message.content.startswith is not a function`

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Likely your node doesn't have this feature, or `content` is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code:

```js
const prefix = '!';

module.exports = {
    name: 'messageCreate',
    once: false,
    execute(client, message) {
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        if (!message.content.startWith(prefix)) return; 
// the above line should read as below

        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
        const cmdName = args.shift().toLowerCase()
        if (cmdName.length == 0) return;

        let cmd = client.commands.get(cmdName)
        if (cmd) cmd.run(client, message, args)
    }
}
```

the function is startsWith, not startWith

```js
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
```